# The multiplication map $\mathrm{GL}(n,k)\times\mathrm{GL}(n,k)\to\mathrm{GL}(n,k)$ such that $A\times B\mapsto AB$ is a morphism.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties

I have to show that the multiplication map $\mathrm{GL}(n,k)\times\mathrm{GL}(n,k)\to\mathrm{GL}(n,k)$ such that $A\times B\mapsto AB$ is a morphism of affine algebraic sets.

I know that given affine algebraic sets $V\subset\mathbb{A}^n$, $W\subset\mathbb{A}^m$ over an algebraically closed field $K$, a map $f:V\to W$ is a morphism if for every $v\in V$, we will get polyomials $p_i\in K[X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n]$, $i\in\{1,2,\cdots,m\}$ such that $f(v)=(p_1(v),p_2(v),\cdots,p_m(v))$.

So, what are the required polynomials for the multiplication map?

**P.S**. A hint would be enough.

Comment: Do you know the formula for matrix multiplication? Also, you got your quantifiers wrong for defining a morphism. It's not that polynomials exist for each $v \in V$ separately. If the polynomials chosen can depend of $v$ then every set map would satisfy this.

Comment: @paul blart math cop correct me if I am wrong, the definition of a morphism would be: Given affine algebraic sets $V\subset\mathbb{A}^n$, $W\subset\mathbb{A}^m$ over an algebraically closed field $K$, a map $f:V\to W$ is a morphism if there are polyomials $p_i\in K[X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n]$, $i\in\{1,2,\cdots,m\}$ such that for every $v\in V$, $f(v)=(p_1(v),p_2(v),\cdots,p_m(v))$. Yes, I know the formula for matrix multiplication. But how can we write it in the form of a polynomial?

Comment: Are all the polynomials constant?

Comment: That definition of a morphism is correct. And no, the polynomials are not constant. Here's another thing to think about. What's a good way to write the coordinates on $GL_n(k)$? You could take $X_1, \dots, X_n, X_{n+1}, \dots, X_{n^2}$ but is there a more natural way to write these coordinates? This may help find these polynomials.

Comment: @paul blart math cop So, if $v=(X,Y)\in\mathrm{GL}(n,k)\times\mathrm{GL}(n,k)$, then we take the polynomials $p_{ij}(X,Y)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{ik}y_{kj}$, $i,j\in\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$, where $X=(x_{ij})$ and $Y=(y_{ij})$ . Is it correct?